# Fallo con formulario Wordpress mensaje Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

En un sitio Wordpress con el tema Zenith existe un cuestionario. Al completarlo el botón debe enviar a otro archivo php en el cual se procesan los datos y luego se envía un correo al usuario con sus resultados. Esto justamente es el síntoma: el usuario no recibe un correo a pesar de que se muestra el mensaje de confirmación del correcto envío del cuestionario.

Revisando la consola me encuentro con que aparece un Uncaught Reference Error:

[image: Esta es una captura del momento en que pulso el botón Enviar del formulario]

Entonces la información nunca llega a la página procesa-oq.php que es la encargada de procesar la información y enviar el correo al usuario.

El código de la página del cuestionario es el siguiente (solo dejé la primera y la última de las preguntas porque es muy largo):

```html
<?php  
/* 
Template Name: Cuestionario OQ ingles
*/  
get_header(); 
global $PAGE_ID;
$options = get_option('infinite_options');
?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
$featured_image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
$featured_image = $featured_image_array[0];
$sidebar = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), SYSTEM_VAR_PREFIX."select_sidebar", true);

if ($sidebar)
{
?> 
    <div id="inner-content">
<?php
}
else
{
?>
    <div class="one">
<?php
}

if ($featured_image != "")
{
?> 
<p><img src="<?php echo $featured_image; ?>" alt=""></p>
<?php
}
the_content();
?>
<!--Inicio todo el documento-->
<div id="contenedor">
<!--Inicio del Contenido-->

<div id="contenido">
  <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="textocontenido">
    <tr>
      <td >&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >
 <center>     
      
      <?php
if (!$HTTP_POST_VARS){ } 
?>


<form action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/procesa_oq_ingles.php" method=post> 
<table  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td height="7" colspan="6" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="14" colspan="6" align="center">Outcomes Questionnaire (OQ-45.2)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="7" colspan="6"><hr /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Name:</td>
          <td colspan="4"><label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="textfield">
          </label></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Age:</td>
          <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="edad" id="textfield2"></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">E-Mail:</td>
          <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="correo" id="textfield3"></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">Instructions: Looking back over the last week, including today, help us understand how you have been feeling.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="131" height="23" align="center">Never</td>
          <td width="87" align="center">Rarely</td>
          <td width="86" align="center">Sometimes</td>
          <td width="97" align="center">Frequently</td>
          <td width="121" align="center">Almost Always</td>
        </tr>


<!-- FIRST QUESTION -->

        <tr>
          <td width="382">1.  I get along well with others.</td>
          <td colspan="5" align="center"><table width="430" height="25" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="86" align="center"><label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="4" id="RadioGroup1_0" />
              </label></td>
              <td width="86" align="center"><label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="3" id="RadioGroup1_1" />
              </label></td>
              <td width="86" align="center"><label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="2" id="RadioGroup1_2" />
              </label></td>
              <td width="86" align="center"><label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="1" id="RadioGroup1_3" />
              </label></td>
              <td width="86" align="center"><label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="0" id="RadioGroup1_4" />
              </label></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6"><hr /></td>
        </tr>
        
<!-- LAST QUESTION -->

        <tr>
          <td height="12" valign="top" class="Estilo4">45.  I have headaches.</td>
          <td colspan="5" align="center"><table width="430" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="86" align="center"><label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup45" value="0" id="RadioGroup45_0" />
              </label></td>
              <td width="86" align="center"><label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup45" value="1" id="RadioGroup45_1" />
              </label></td>
              <td width="86" align="center"><label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup45" value="2" id="RadioGroup45_2" />
              </label></td>
              <td width="86" align="center"><label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup45" value="3" id="RadioGroup45_3" />
              </label></td>
              <td width="86" align="center"><label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup45" value="4" id="RadioGroup45_4" />
              </label></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="2" colspan="6" valign="top" class="Estilo4"><hr /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6" valign="top" class="Estilo4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6" align="center"><input type=submit value="Send" onClick="ValidaMail(correo)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</form>
   
      
     </center> </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!--Fin del Contenido-->

</div>

<!--Fin todo el documento-->
    </div><!--END ONE-->
<?php
if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), SYSTEM_VAR_PREFIX."add_class_title", true) != "no")
{
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".one :header, #inner-content :header").addClass("title");
    $(".team-member-info :header, .no_title").removeClass("title");
    $(".pricing-info :header, .no_title").removeClass("title");
})    
    
</script>
<?php
} 

if ($sidebar) get_sidebar(); 

?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?> 
        
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Si quieren ver en vivo lo que pasa, el siguiente [enlace a la página del cuestionario](http://iemp.cl/en/outcomes-questionnaire-oq-45-2/) en donde podrán ver el problema.

Intenté borrando el evento `onclick` pero no me resultó, al parecer wordpress no toma en cuenta el cambio o algo así...

No sé qué más hacer ¿alguien tiene alguna sugerencia de por dónde buscar o qué hacer?

Desde ya muchas gracias !!!

Comment: Al hacer click en el mensaje `(index):1368` puedo ver que apunta a la línea donde está el botón `<input type=submit value="Send" onClick="ValidaMail(correo)">` o sea está más que claro que el problema es la validación del correo, pero no logro encontrar el archivo JS que pueda contener la validación (en el peor de los casos pensaba en borrar la validación y que funcionaría, pero sigue ocurriendo el problema)...

Comment: Intenta [borrando caché](https://www.hostinger.mx/tutoriales/cache-wordpress) para que cargue los cambios.

Comment: Gracias @Triby obviamente fue lo primero que hice...

Comment: en la response hay rastros del endurance cache , desactivale momentaneamente desde plugins y seguramente refresque el template. tema aparte hacer un post a un php dentro del theme no es muy wordpress, se ve que hay un contact form 7 y un mailchimp instalados, considera armar el cuestionario y envío con esas herramientas